# Redirect after login to previous page

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

I would like to know how I can redirect to any page after login I tried the codes below and they do not work I get an error saying redirected you too many times. How can I fix this?

This code is for my login page:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (!(isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email'] != '')) {

header ("Location: log-in/login");

}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

This is for the page that gets redirected after login:

```
<?PHP

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) 
   $url = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
else 
   $url = "http://torcdesign.com"; 

header("Location: http://torcdesign.com$url"); ?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
```

Comment: hard to make much sense of this

Comment: Looks like you are redirecting back to the login page whenever `$_SESSION['email']` is not set.  So you just keep redirecting.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: after login redirect back to previous page

Answer (score 2):

The page that gets redirected, instead of:

```
header("Location: http://torcdesign.com$url"); ?>
```

must be

```
header("Location: " . $url); ?>
```

and your login page should not redirect to, what i see, the same login page, it must redirect to an authenticaded page if your session variable is not empty.